# how to write the pyspark output to impala table?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, bigdata, impala

Am using pyspark for my problem statement, here, I am suppose to combine my outputs and give as an input to my other model.  But in hdfs, my output gets split into parts and hence it is difficult to combine them.

So I wanted to store the output results to impala table directly, how can I do it ?

Comment: What's wrong with `saveAsTable`? Or using SparkSQL to run an INSERT INTO existing table? Also, HDFS can read an entire directory for input, so it's not clear if you're asking for a single file or not

Answer (score 1):

To expose the contents of files stored in HDFS as a table, you can define an **external table**:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name
( column_1 string
, ... )

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE

LOCATION '/some/path/in/hdfs/';
```

Different file formats are supported. The example is for flat files with tab as a column separator.

If you want to change the number of files produced by Spark, you can change the number of RDD partitions with `rdd.coalesce` before saving it.

Comment: I have a large output to be saved, if that gets saved on a single node, then ill run into memory issues

Comment: There's no need to try to save the output into a single file, but `coalesce` can still lower the number of files from 1000 to - let's say - 20. But you don't have to do that - the external table will show data from all the files in its location.